# symfony2 where to store reusable bundle

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

Question is where to store reusable bundle?

Example.
There is few application (AppA, AppB, AppC) that uses My/ReportsBundle.

All those apps have `composer.json`

```
"require": "my/reports-bundle:1.0.x-dev"
```

Now. When any developer needs to make changes to `My/ReportsBundle`, he goes vendor/my/reports-bundle/My/ReportsBundle directory.
Make changes.
Commit them to git.

then others can just use `composer update` to get updates.

But there is constant mentions that we should avoid to alter `vendor` contents.

So, my question what is best practice for placing and developing reusable symfony2 bundle?

Comment: In this scenario, working under vendor is fine.  Most of the cautions concern modifying other people's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple apps using single package, you have to treat it like an open source package. Develop is standalone and tagged. Because fixing package in your AppA, could break it in AppB without even it's use knowing.

So I'd maintain standalone package, like you'd like to contribute some package on Githubu.

Comment: main question is there any way how we can place such bundle in src dir, and how it can be updated easily?

and, thx for the answer.

Comment: It depends on your context. If there would be 1 app using the package, it would be simple. As there is multiple apps, it depends how many programmers does it use. If only you, you could symlink single repository to all apps.

Comment: The best workflow for your usecase as you described, you already do. So I would probably stick with that. Personally I'd maintain standalone repository with tests, just to keep everybody aware and up to date. Also it would provide experience you can use in future package decoupling.